# Adjust image size to browser

Tags: css, image, wordpress, browser, scale

I am using an array/loop to get my images from a custom field, called gallery (Wordpress). The retrieved images are not resized, which means that they are max 150px width OR max 150px height. Now i am wondering how i can automatically let these images adjust to the browser size. Chrome does that perfectly but IE and FF do not. When i set img { width:100%;} the resizing works but then the size of the images themselves is screwed, as you can imagine.

Is there any other possibility to let the images automatically adjust to the browser size?
Thanks for yr time!

Comment: I assume that you mean they're pixelated, rather than a particular problem with their size?

Comment: Hey i have images within a table with different height's and width's so i can not set a percentage for the images since they all differ. However only when i set a percentage to the images they adjust when i am resizing my browser. As i can not use percentage is there another way to make them fit my browser?

Comment: Yes, but i have images with different width and height. i have images 150x99 px and images 99x150 pxSo lets say that the ratio aspect is different. Guess i can not use percentages right?

Comment: You can use percentages. That's my point. If you fix the width (or height), the browser will calculate the property not defined for you. See a demo here > http://jsfiddle.net/FHwhw/. Notice how the images are the same width, but different heights.

Comment: Hi thanks. Ok maybe i can but i do not see how (sorry). I took a look at your example, but my images have different width's (and height's).. So image:50%; would not do right?

Comment: YES! It is 50% of the container width, not 50% of the original width of the image.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/wzshop/wTeMt/18/ this is what i get, the width of the bottom, smaller, image scales to the wider image above.. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Try adding `height: 100%` and no width.

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/wzshop/wTeMt/21/

Comment: I don't understand what you actually want? The last Fiddle looks good to me.

Comment: Hmm. Here is what i want: http://zakelijkeweblog.nl/images.png
instead of the at the bottom right taking the whole width of the image above

Comment: Why should the bottom right image a different width? Because it is portrait instead of landscape?

Comment: Yes but the thumbnail width is less than the thumbnail width of the other images so it stretches. Not that neat.

Comment: Solution for me was to give a static width for images in the css for every relevant media screen width

i.e.
`@media only screen and ( max-width: 479px ) {
}`

Comment: how about usign background-size: cover // full width and height or using background-size: contain // maintain the aspect ratio of the image and also add background-repeat- no-repeat

Answer (score 1):

```
#img.source-image
{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Should do the trick.

Also, make your question more clear.

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/ has some decent examples.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Hope it was all clear. But anyway this did not fixed it for me. I have images within a table, that have different width and height. So setting the width for images to 100%, or any percentage, would not work. So i am looking for another fix to make them automatically adjust to the browser

Comment: You could try resizing them with some algorithm and then load images depending on the screen size, SimpleImage could do the job:

http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php

Or just add / remove certain classes to the images corresponding to the screen size, use fixed pixels instead of percentage if It's giving you hell.

Answer (score 1):

try not to display images inside tables, since a table needs to load every cell before any of it will be displayed, increasing download to view time. Also wherever possible, try and not let the browser resize any image. You can do this yourself with alot better results. You can define in css to detect screen sizes. Then set a series of screen sizes to lead different images, eg if window.width < 800px{load 800pxImage}, if window.width > 800px{load 1600pxImage}
this way you can compensate for the vast variety of browser windows, since there is no way that one design will work great on ALL machines. This may produce more code and require a little more research but you should look into it.
Here is an example using HTML & CSS:

HTML
/* standard body and div setup to create a responding site that changes its size with each browser window, this is a good method to allow the browser to adjust block sections */

```
<body class="background">
     <div id="content" class="etc">
         .....
         ....
      </div>
</body>
```

CSS

/* create a simple css file to include basic settings */

```
body {
   font: 100%/1.4, Verdana, Geneva, Sans serif;
   margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
   width: 100%; Height: 100%; }

div #content {
   width: 75%;
   text-align: center; }

/*Apply as default image to use if the window does not meat any criteria */
body.background {
   background-image: url(../Images/YourImage1600px);
   background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

/*determine if the screen size is equal to or smaller than 800px, if it is load and use the css inside the determining brackets. You can have multiple statements to determine multiple settings. For neat code, you could place all the new requirements into a seperate css file and inside the query statement, just link to the css file. so technically you could have a single individual css file that is used for nothing but to determine user requirements and load other css files

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
    body.background {
        background-image: url(../Images/YourImage800px);
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    }
}
```

i hope you can make sense of all of this and it helps.